# SSH mount via fstab fails because of root ssh passphrase

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, arch-linux, fstab

At work, we have a dev environment I want to mount so I can work on it locally on Arch with i3 (Manjaro i3).

I have SSH and an SSHFS mount set up on my devenv which runs without issues, along with `gnome-keyring` so user `sea` doesn't need to type a passphrase after boot/login.

- `fstab` line:

  ```bsh
  /mnt/workdir fuse.sshfs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,follow_symlinks,user,idmap=user,identityfile=/home/sea/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
  ```

  On boot, I get error `Too many levels of symbolic links` when I `ls` the directory, but I suspect symlinks aren't the issue since typing the passphrase after `sudo umount -a`/`sudo mount -a` works, as does the `fstab` mount after removing the passphrase, but this is not the solution I'm looking for.

My `gnome-keyring` makes sure user `sea` doesn't have to type the passphrase, but `fstab` runs as root; is there any workaround besides removing the passphrase?

Both `fstab` and `gnome-keyring` is set up according to the Arch [SSHFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS) and [`gnome-keyring`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring) wikis.

Comment: I'd take it out of fstab and mount on my first login instead. If you have ssh key added to agents and forwarded, it may work as desired. Never tried.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how to mount it instead of fstab? Im still somewhat new to linux, so my first idea was to put it in my bashrc file, but that wasnt a good idea since it of course would then try to mount on every terminal opening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `/etc/profile` to SSHFS mount, instead of `fstab`, which works as intended; however, any feedback or a better solution is welcomed.